# How to get custom tolerance effect for .droppable()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I've got a draggable `#box` div that I can drop onto one of multiple droppable `.ru` divs. The height of `#box` is about 3 times the height of a `.ru` div, however, so I'm playing around with the `tolerance` option of `.droppable`, but nothing seems to fit what I want.

I'd like for `#box` to be hovering over one of the droppables based on when the top third of `#box` is over one of the droppables.

I tried out using `tolerance: pointer` and setting the `.draggable()` option `cursorAt: {top: 15}`, but this makes `#box` jump to a new position when dragging is initiated, which I don't want.

I'm now trying adding a child div, `#test` 15px from the top of `#box`, and I'm wondering if there is a way for hovering to be activated on a `.ru` when `#test` is over that `.ru`? Or, alternatively, is there a good way to get hovering to activate as I've described that does not use a child div?

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/joL53wkq/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="containment">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="test">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    background-color: teal;
    width: 500px;
    height: 92px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
}  

#test{
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#containment {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 500px;
    height: 800px;
}

.ru {
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JS:**

```
for(i=1; i<20; i++){
    $("#containment").append("<div class='ru'>")    
}

$( "#box" ).draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
});

$( ".ru" ).droppable({
    hoverClass: "hover",
    tolerance:"intersect",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.position({
            of: $(this),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left top'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function managing the tolerance is called **intersect**, you could redefine it and add a custom tolerance option. Something like this seems to work, it may need some tweaking and testing, but it should give you some ideas:

```
$.ui.intersect = function(draggable, droppable, toleranceMode) {

    if (!droppable.offset) {
        return false;
    }

    var draggableLeft, draggableTop,
        x1 = (draggable.positionAbs || draggable.position.absolute).left,
        y1 = (draggable.positionAbs || draggable.position.absolute).top,
        x2 = x1 + draggable.helperProportions.width,
        y2 = y1 + draggable.helperProportions.height,
        l = droppable.offset.left,
        t = droppable.offset.top,
        r = l + droppable.proportions.width,
        b = t + droppable.proportions.height;

    switch (toleranceMode) {
  case "custom":
  //you can define your rules here
            return (l < x1 + (draggable.helperProportions.width / 2) && // Right Half
                x2 - (draggable.helperProportions.width / 2) < r && // Left Half
                t < y1 && // Bottom Half
                b > y1 + 15 ); // Top Half
        case "fit":
            return (l <= x1 && x2 <= r && t <= y1 && y2 <= b);
        case "intersect":
            return (l < x1 + (draggable.helperProportions.width / 2) && // Right Half
                x2 - (draggable.helperProportions.width / 2) < r && // Left Half
                t < y1 + (draggable.helperProportions.height / 2) && // Bottom Half
                y2 - (draggable.helperProportions.height / 2) < b ); // Top Half
        case "pointer":
            draggableLeft = ((draggable.positionAbs || draggable.position.absolute).left + (draggable.clickOffset || draggable.offset.click).left);
            draggableTop = ((draggable.positionAbs || draggable.position.absolute).top + (draggable.clickOffset || draggable.offset.click).top);
            return isOverAxis( draggableTop, t, droppable.proportions().height ) && isOverAxis( draggableLeft, l, droppable.proportions().width );
        case "touch":
            return (
                (y1 >= t && y1 <= b) || // Top edge touching
                (y2 >= t && y2 <= b) || // Bottom edge touching
                (y1 < t && y2 > b)      // Surrounded vertically
            ) && (
                (x1 >= l && x1 <= r) || // Left edge touching
                (x2 >= l && x2 <= r) || // Right edge touching
                (x1 < l && x2 > r)      // Surrounded horizontally
            );
        default:
            return false;
        }

};
for(i=1; i<20; i++){
  $("#containment").append("<div class='ru'>")    
}


$( "#box" ).draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
});


$( ".ru" ).droppable({
  hoverClass: "hover",
  tolerance:"custom",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.draggable.position({
      of: $(this),
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top'
    });
  }
});
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/nxkfcwpp/1/